# ClassCastException by optaplanner solver.solve()

Tags: java, classcastexception, optaplanner, spring-boot-devtools

Now that I know that this error is related to spring-boot-devtools, and that the error will not occur if spring-boot-devtools is removed, I wonder if there is a solution without removing spring-boot-devtools

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bugu.queen.persistence.mongodb.domain.period.PeriodSolution cannot be cast to com.bugu.queen.persistence.mongodb.domain.period.PeriodSolution
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.LambdaBeanPropertyMemberAccessor.executeGetter(LambdaBeanPropertyMemberAccessor.java:103)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.getScore(SolutionDescriptor.java:1134)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:215)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:218)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:210)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:190)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.Solver$solve.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at com.bugu.queen.service.CourseScheduleService.solve(CourseScheduleService.groovy:620)
    at com.bugu.queen.service.CourseScheduleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6b1e6706.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.bugu.queen.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
```

Comment: Is your dev-tools and spring-boot-starter versions equal ?

Comment: yes，both are in version 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: you can exclude mongodb dependencies from anyone so there will be only one `PeriodSolution` class

Comment: That's not going to work

Comment: Try it first. Then you see

Comment: Thank you, I think I probably know how to change, you are right, make sure only one PeriodSolution class